# Apex Code related query

Tags: apex

I have a custom object and need to display the first entry made in the object using a lookup account field.

This account is common for all entries and should also display the first ID of the other custom object that is related to this.

Any suggestion on how can this be achieved.

Comment: What do you mean by "Account" is common for all entries in your custom object?

Comment: Account ID is related to the other details of the custom object. My custom object is Account__r and another is Approach__c when any one approaches a new record is created in Approach object where ID of Account object is common for a single person.  I need to display the very first Approach__c details for an account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about [limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm) clause in SOQL.

If the other custom object (say objB) is child of your main custom object (say objA) then the SOQL would be (you would use plural name of object here)

```
SELECT id, name, (SELECT Id FROM objBs) FROM objA WHERE Account__c =: AccountId ORDER BY createddate desc LIMIT 1
```

and if your other custom object is parent of your main custom object then soql would be

```
SELECT id, name, objB.Id FROM objA WHERE Account__c =: AccountId ORDER BY createddate desc LIMIT 1
```